# Multiple targets from one script, copying to multiple different directories in Makefile

Tags: python, csv, makefile

### Scenario

I am working on updating a script that generates source code files for both **C** and **Java** at build time, for each of our builds.
This needs to run on both Windows and Linux.
Two file types need to be created for each language: **Enums** and **Tables**.

Each set of four files (C Enum, C Table, Java Enum, Java Table) is generated from a corresponding CSV file.
Given an input CSV file called `A.csv`, the output files are `AEnum.inc`, `ATable.inc`, `AEnum.java`, and `ATable.java`.

All four files can be created at once by calling a python script, with an activated venv, like so:

```
python main.py --input A.csv --output ./output --enum-c --table-c --enum-java --table-java
```

This is shortened in the makefile with a function called `run_autogen_all`.

Once the files have been created, they need to be copied to different directories:

- C enums & tables go in `$(C_AUTOGEN)/`
- Java enums go in `$(JAVA_ENUM)/`
- Java tables go in `$(JAVA_TABLE)/`

### Problem

I have not been able to figure out how to ensure the python script runs only once (runtime is non-negligible), while also copying all of the files to the correct directories.

How can I achieve this behavior with Make?

### Attempted solution

Here is my current solution that *works*, but it runs the python script twice and copies files twice.

```
MAIN_4_CSV_FILES = A.CSV B.CSV C.CSV D.CSV E.CSV F.CSV G.CSV H.CSV I.CSV J.CSV K.CSV L.CSV M.CSV N.CSV O.CSV P.CSV Q.CSV R.CSV S.CSV T.CSV U.CSV V.CSV W.CSV X.CSV Y.CSV Z.CSV
.PHONY : JavaFiles CFiles
JavaFiles : *.java
CFiles : *.inc

*.java *.inc : $(MAIN_4_CSV_FILES)
    $(call run_autogen_all,$^)
    $(COPYF) *Enum.java $(JAVA_ENUM)
    $(COPYF) *Table.java $(JAVA_TABLE)
    $(COPYF) *.inc $(C_AUTOGEN)
```

Running `make JavaFiles CFiles -n` gives the following output

```
python "../../../../../build/Common/CSV_Parser/autogenerate_from_csv.py" --output "./" --csv-files A.CSV B.CSV C.CSV D.CSV E.CSV F.CSV G.CSV H.CSV I.CSV J.CSV K.CSV L.CSV M.CSV N.CSV O.CSV P.CSV Q.CSV R.CSV S.CSV T.CSV U.CSV V.CSV W.CSV X.CSV Y.CSV Z.CSV
cp -f *Enum.java ../../../../Project/java/enums
cp -f *Table.java ../../../../Project/java/tables
cp -f *Enum.inc ../../../../Project/c
cp -f *Table.inc ../../../../Project/c
python "../../../../../build/Common/CSV_Parser/autogenerate_from_csv.py" --output "./" --csv-files A.CSV B.CSV C.CSV D.CSV E.CSV F.CSV G.CSV H.CSV I.CSV J.CSV K.CSV L.CSV M.CSV N.CSV O.CSV P.CSV Q.CSV R.CSV S.CSV T.CSV U.CSV V.CSV W.CSV X.CSV Y.CSV Z.CSV
cp -f *Enum.java ../../../../Project/java/enums
cp -f *Table.java ../../../../Project/java/tables
cp -f *Enum.inc ../../../../Project/c
cp -f *Table.inc ../../../../Project/c
```

#### Previous attempts

I've tried many options, here are a few that didn't work

```
%Enum.inc %Enum.java %Table.inc %Table.java :
    $(call run_autogen_all,$<)
    $(call copy_attrib,$(notdir $@),$@)

AFiles = $(C_AUTOGEN)/AEnum.c $(C_AUTOGEN)/ATable.c $(JAVA_ENUM)/AEnum.java $(JAVA_TABLE)/ATable.java
$(AFiles) : A.csv
[...]
```

```
JavaEnums : $(JAVA_ENUM)/AEnum.java $(JAVA_ENUM)/BEnum.java [...]

$(JAVA_ENUM)/%Enum.java : %Enum.java
    $(call run_autogen_all,$*.csv)
    $(call copy_attrib,$(notdir $@),$@)
[...]
```

```
%Enum.java %Enum.c %Table.java %Table.c : %.csv
    $(call run_autogen_all,$<)
    $(call copy_attrib,$(notdir $@),$@)
[...]
```

I also tried messing with `.INTERMEDIATE` and `.SECONDARY` to no avail.

Comment: This is not a duplicate: I have not been able to find an existing question that combines multiple targets from a single script invocation along with copying files to multiple directories.

Comment: Have you tried grouped targets (introduced in v4.3)? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html

Comment: Your last attempt is almost right: it would be right IF all the prerequisites and targets were in the working directory.  But as Renaud shows, if you want to put them in a different directory you have to tell make where they went.  Else, how can it find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use GNU make and all generated files are generated in the current directory you can use a pattern rule with 4 targets.

```
MAIN_4_CSV_FILES := $(wildcard *.CSV)
TARGETS          := $(patsubst %.CSV,$(C_AUTOGEN)/%Enum.inc,$(MAIN_4_CSV_FILES))
TARGETS          += $(patsubst %.CSV,$(C_AUTOGEN)/%Table.inc,$(MAIN_4_CSV_FILES))
TARGETS          += $(patsubst %.CSV,$(JAVA_ENUM)/%Enum.java,$(MAIN_4_CSV_FILES))
TARGETS          += $(patsubst %.CSV,$(JAVA_TABLE)/%Table.java,$(MAIN_4_CSV_FILES))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)

$(C_AUTOGEN)/%Enum.inc $(C_AUTOGEN)/%Table.inc $(JAVA_ENUM)/%Enum.java $(JAVA_TABLE)/%Table.java: %.CSV
   python main.py --input $< --output ./output --enum-c --table-c --enum-java --table-java
   mv $*Enum.inc $*Table.inc $(C_AUTOGEN)
   mv $*Enum.java $(JAVA_ENUM)
   mv $*Table.java $(JAVA_TABLE)
```

GNU make considers the 4 targets as [grouped](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-targets_002c-grouped) and runs the recipe only once to build them. Don't use `$@` in the recipes of such rules (at least not before you read [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-targets_002c-grouped)).

Once you will have tested this try maybe to re-introduce your macros.

Comment: I thought you needed the &: separator for grouped targets...?

Comment: Not for pattern rules. Multi-targets pattern rules are always considered as grouped. See [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro): _ Multiple target patterns in pattern rules are always treated as grouped targets_.

Comment: TIL. Does that mean grouped targets were supported before 4.3 by the use of pattern rules?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Before 4.3 there was a kind of way of grouped targets with patterns rule.